# Format plain math expression in MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax, mathml

Given the math expression `x = 1 / 2 + 3`

I need to display it formatted with MathJax. If you look in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/nr4z9dev/5/), you'll see that's incorrect:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this without manually formatting the string?

**UPDATE**

This is the intent: a user will enter a math expression in a text field on the UI, and I need to format that expression appropriately with MathJax (in an output field below the input field). Note that the user doesn't know MathJax or Latex so they will enter a value such as `x = 1 / 2 + 3`.

In my example I tried just replacing `/` with `\over` but that didn't work (the first equation above) and I had to manually make some adjustments to get it correctly (see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/nr4z9dev/5/)). So the question is: having a math expression in a string variable, is there a way to display it correctly in MathJax without adjusting it manually (for example, without adding manually `{}`?

Comment: "*If I convert it directly to MathJax*", how are you doing that? You seem to know how to get the correct formatting, what is your real issue?

Comment: Please take a look at the update, I clarified the question

Comment: I guess the trivial (and unhelpful) answer is "probably". What you need to do is parse the input, work out the formatting rules to apply, then apply them (e.g. to convert `x = 1 / 2 + 3` to `\[x = {1 \over 2 }+ 3\]`). SO isn't the place to ask someone to do that for you, it's intended to help you with code you've written yourself, or with using libraries and frameworks. :-)

Comment: Also there are also multiple ways to display the same expression, e.g. `3*1/2+3` can be either `\[x = {3 \times 1 \over 2} + 3\]` vs `\[x = 3 \times {1 \over 2} + 3\]` depending on how you want it look (e.g. highlight common denominators, expressions, factors, etc.).

Comment: Have you tried the AsciiMath input format rather than TeX?  That corresponds more to "natural" text entry, and it does format you expression in the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for